# [SingleQueryHandler]: evaluate: message=Query failed. Errors: [], stack=FabricError: Query failed. Errors: [] Hyperledger Fabric SDK 2.2

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

I am running Fabric Node SDK 2.2. The issue I am facing while querying the ledger is this.

```
error: [SingleQueryHandler]: evaluate: message=Query failed. Errors: [], stack=FabricError: Query failed. Errors: []
    at SingleQueryHandler.evaluate (/fabric23/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/impl/query/singlequeryhandler.js:47:23)
    at Transaction.evaluate (/fabric23/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:276:49)
    at ContractImpl.evaluateTransaction (/fabric23/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/contract.js:179:45)
    at main (/fabric23/test.js:69:40)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5), name=FabricError
Failed to evaluate transaction: FabricError: Query failed. Errors: []
```

So I set the debug log location and found that the singlequeryhandler.js constructor is getting passed an empty list of peers. However before that the log shows that it was able to connect to all the peers and orderers in the network. Not sure if I am doing something wrong. Adding the *s around the constructor log line to make it spottable.

```
debug: Successfully constructed a winston logger with configurations error=error.log, debug=debug.log, info=console
debug: [crypto_ecdsa_aes]: Hash algorithm: SHA2, hash output size: 256
debug: [Gateway]: in Gateway constructor
debug: [Gateway]: connect - start
debug: [Gateway]: connection options: {"wallet":{"providerRegistry":{"providers":{}},"store":{"storePath":"wallet"}},"identity":"org2user","discovery":{"enabled":false,"asLocalhost":false},"clientTlsIdentity":"tlsid"}
debug: [Client]: Client.constructor[gateway client] - start 
debug: [Gateway]: connect - setting identity from wallet
debug: [crypto_ecdsa_aes]: createKeyFromRaw - start
debug: [crypto_ecdsa_aes]: createKeyFromRaw - have the key [Circular]
debug: [crypto_ecdsa_aes]: createKeyFromRaw - start
debug: [crypto_ecdsa_aes]: createKeyFromRaw - have the key [Circular]
debug: [Gateway]: connect - setting tlsIdentity
debug: [Client]: setTlsClientCertAndKey: gateway client - start
debug: [Gateway]: connect - NetworkConfig loading client from ccp
debug: [NetworkConfig]: loadFromConfig - start
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildPeer - start - peer1.peers.org1.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: findPeerMspid - start for peer1.peers.org1.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: findPeerMspid - checking peer peer1.peers.org2.com in org ORG2MSP
dPeerMspid - checking peer peer2.peers.org2.com in org ORG2MSP
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildOptions - start
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client - start
debug: [Client]: getConnectionOptions: gateway client - start
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client grpc-wait-for-ready-timeout set to 3000
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client requestTimeout set to 12000
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client - ssl_target_name_override: peer1.peers.org1.com
debug: [Endpoint]: Endpoint.constructor - start 
debug: [Client]: new endpoint url: grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7051
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildPeer - about to connect to endorser peer1.peers.org1.com url:grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7051 mspid:undefined
debug: [Client]: getEndorser: gateway client start name:peer1.peers.org1.com
debug: [Client]: getEndorser: gateway client create endorser name:peer1.peers.org1.com
debug: [Endorser]: Endorser.constructor[peer1.peers.org1.com] - start 
debug: [Client]: getEndorser: gateway client return endorser name:peer1.peers.org1.com
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: connect[Endorser-peer1.peers.org1.com] - start 
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: connect[Endorser-peer1.peers.org1.com] - create the grpc service for peer1.peers.org1.com
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - start Endorser-peer1.peers.org1.com - grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7051
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - promise running peer1.peers.org1.com - grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7051
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Successfully connected to remote gRPC server peer1.peers.org1.com url:grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7051
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: connect[Endorser-peer1.peers.org1.com] - end - completed the waitForReady for peer1.peers.org1.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildPeer - connected to endorser peer1.peers.org1.com url:grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7051
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildPeer - start - peer1.peers.org3.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: findPeerMspid - start for peer1.peers.org3.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: findPeerMspid - checking peer peer1.peers.org2.com in org ORG2MSP
debug: [NetworkConfig]: findPeerMspid - checking peer peer2.peers.org2.com in org ORG2MSP
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildOptions - start
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client - start
debug: [Client]: getConnectionOptions: gateway client - start
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client grpc-wait-for-ready-timeout set to 3000
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client requestTimeout set to 12000
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client - ssl_target_name_override: peer1.peers.org3.com
debug: [Endpoint]: Endpoint.constructor - start 
debug: [Client]: new endpoint url: grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7051
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildPeer - about to connect to endorser peer1.peers.org3.com url:grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7051 mspid:undefined
debug: [Client]: getEndorser: gateway client start name:peer1.peers.org3.com
debug: [Client]: getEndorser: gateway client create endorser name:peer1.peers.org3.com
debug: [Endorser]: Endorser.constructor[peer1.peers.org3.com] - start 
debug: [Client]: getEndorser: gateway client return endorser name:peer1.peers.org3.com
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: connect[Endorser-peer1.peers.org3.com] - start 
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: connect[Endorser-peer1.peers.org3.com] - create the grpc service for peer1.peers.org3.com
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - start Endorser-peer1.peers.org3.com - grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7051
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - promise running peer1.peers.org3.com - grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7051
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Successfully connected to remote gRPC server peer1.peers.org3.com url:grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7051
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: connect[Endorser-peer1.peers.org3.com] - end - completed the waitForReady for peer1.peers.org3.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildPeer - connected to endorser peer1.peers.org3.com url:grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7051
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildPeer - start - peer1.peers.org2.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: findPeerMspid - start for peer1.peers.org2.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: findPeerMspid - checking peer peer1.peers.org2.com in org ORG2MSP
debug: [NetworkConfig]: findPeerMspid - found mspid ORG2MSP for peer1.peers.org2.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildOptions - start
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client - start
debug: [Client]: getConnectionOptions: gateway client - start
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client grpc-wait-for-ready-timeout set to 3000
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client requestTimeout set to 12000
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client - ssl_target_name_override: peer1.peers.org2.com
debug: [Endpoint]: Endpoint.constructor - start 
debug: [Client]: new endpoint url: grpcs://10.167.xxx.xxx:7051
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildPeer - about to connect to endorser peer1.peers.org2.com url:grpcs://10.167.xxx.xxx:7051 mspid:ORG2MSP
debug: [Client]: getEndorser: gateway client start name:peer1.peers.org2.com
debug: [Client]: getEndorser: gateway client create endorser name:peer1.peers.org2.com
debug: [Endorser]: Endorser.constructor[peer1.peers.org2.com] - start 
debug: [Client]: getEndorser: gateway client return endorser name:peer1.peers.org2.com
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: connect[Endorser-peer1.peers.org2.com] - start 
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: connect[Endorser-peer1.peers.org2.com] - create the grpc service for peer1.peers.org2.com
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - start Endorser-peer1.peers.org2.com - grpcs://10.167.xxx.xxx:7051
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - promise running peer1.peers.org2.com - grpcs://10.167.xxx.xxx:7051
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Successfully connected to remote gRPC server peer1.peers.org2.com url:grpcs://10.167.xxx.xxx:7051
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: connect[Endorser-peer1.peers.org2.com] - end - completed the waitForReady for peer1.peers.org2.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildPeer - connected to endorser peer1.peers.org2.com url:grpcs://10.167.xxx.xxx:7051
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildOrderer - start - ord1.orderers.org1.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildOptions - start
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client - start
debug: [Client]: getConnectionOptions: gateway client - start
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client grpc-wait-for-ready-timeout set to 3000
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client requestTimeout set to 12000
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client - ssl_target_name_override: ord1.orderers.org1.com
debug: [Endpoint]: Endpoint.constructor - start 
debug: [Client]: new endpoint url: grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7050
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildOrderer - about to connect to committer ord1.orderers.org1.com url:grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7050 mspid:undefined
debug: [Client]: getCommitter: gateway client start name:ord1.orderers.org1.com
debug: [Client]: getCommitter: gateway client create committer name:ord1.orderers.org1.com
debug: [Committer]: Committer.constructor[ord1.orderers.org1.com] - start 
debug: [Client]: getCommitter: gateway client return committer name:ord1.orderers.org1.com
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: connect[Committer-ord1.orderers.org1.com] - start 
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: connect[Committer-ord1.orderers.org1.com] - create the grpc service for ord1.orderers.org1.com
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - start Committer-ord1.orderers.org1.com - grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7050
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - promise running ord1.orderers.org1.com - grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7050
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Successfully connected to remote gRPC server ord1.orderers.org1.com url:grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7050
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: connect[Committer-ord1.orderers.org1.com] - end - completed the waitForReady for ord1.orderers.org1.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildOrderer - connected to committer ord1.orderers.org1.com url:grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7050
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildOrderer - start - ord2.orderers.org1.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildOptions - start
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client - start
debug: [Client]: getConnectionOptions: gateway client - start
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client grpc-wait-for-ready-timeout set to 3000
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client requestTimeout set to 12000
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client - ssl_target_name_override: ord2.orderers.org1.com
debug: [Endpoint]: Endpoint.constructor - start 
debug: [Client]: new endpoint url: grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7050
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildOrderer - about to connect to committer ord2.orderers.org1.com url:grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7050 mspid:undefined
debug: [Client]: getCommitter: gateway client start name:ord2.orderers.org1.com
debug: [Client]: getCommitter: gateway client create committer name:ord2.orderers.org1.com
debug: [Committer]: Committer.constructor[ord2.orderers.org1.com] - start 
debug: [Client]: getCommitter: gateway client return committer name:ord2.orderers.org1.com
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: connect[Committer-ord2.orderers.org1.com] - start 
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: connect[Committer-ord2.orderers.org1.com] - create the grpc service for ord2.orderers.org1.com
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - start Committer-ord2.orderers.org1.com - grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7050
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - promise running ord2.orderers.org1.com - grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7050
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Successfully connected to remote gRPC server ord2.orderers.org1.com url:grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7050
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: connect[Committer-ord2.orderers.org1.com] - end - completed the waitForReady for ord2.orderers.org1.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildOrderer - connected to committer ord2.orderers.org1.com url:grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7050
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildOrderer - start - ord3.orderers.org1.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildOptions - start
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client - start
debug: [Client]: getConnectionOptions: gateway client - start
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client grpc-wait-for-ready-timeout set to 3000
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client requestTimeout set to 12000
debug: [Client]: newEndpoint: gateway client - ssl_target_name_override: ord3.orderers.org1.com
debug: [Endpoint]: Endpoint.constructor - start 
debug: [Client]: new endpoint url: grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7050
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildOrderer - about to connect to committer ord3.orderers.org1.com url:grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7050 mspid:undefined
debug: [Client]: getCommitter: gateway client start name:ord3.orderers.org1.com
debug: [Client]: getCommitter: gateway client create committer name:ord3.orderers.org1.com
debug: [Committer]: Committer.constructor[ord3.orderers.org1.com] - start 
debug: [Client]: getCommitter: gateway client return committer name:ord3.orderers.org1.com
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: connect[Committer-ord3.orderers.org1.com] - start 
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: connect[Committer-ord3.orderers.org1.com] - create the grpc service for ord3.orderers.org1.com
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - start Committer-ord3.orderers.org1.com - grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7050
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - promise running ord3.orderers.org1.com - grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7050
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: waitForReady - Successfully connected to remote gRPC server ord3.orderers.org1.com url:grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7050
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: connect[Committer-ord3.orderers.org1.com] - end - completed the waitForReady for ord3.orderers.org1.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildOrderer - connected to committer ord3.orderers.org1.com url:grpcs://10.100.xxx.xxx:7050
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildChannel - start - supplychain
debug: [Client]: getChannel: gateway client start name:supplychain
debug: [Client]: getChannel: gateway client create channel name:supplychain
debug: [Channel]: Channel.constructor[supplychain] - start
debug: [Channel]: Channel.constructor[supplychain] - channel name is good supplychain
debug: [Channel]: Constructed Channel instance: name - supplychain
debug: [Client]: getChannel: gateway client return channel name:supplychain
debug: [Client]: getEndorser: gateway client start name:peer1.peers.org1.com
debug: [Client]: getEndorser: gateway client existing endorser name:peer1.peers.org1.com
debug: [Client]: getEndorser: gateway client return endorser name:peer1.peers.org1.com
debug: [Channel]: addEndorser[supplychain] - start
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: isConnectable[Endorser-peer1.peers.org1.com] - start 
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: isConnectable[Endorser-peer1.peers.org1.com] - this servive endpoint has been connected
debug: [Channel]: addEndorser[supplychain] - adding a new Endorser  --name: peer1.peers.org1.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildChannel - added endorsing peer :: peer1.peers.org1.com
debug: [Client]: getEndorser: gateway client start name:peer1.peers.org3.com
debug: [Client]: getEndorser: gateway client existing endorser name:peer1.peers.org3.com
debug: [Client]: getEndorser: gateway client return endorser name:peer1.peers.org3.com
debug: [Channel]: addEndorser[supplychain] - start
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: isConnectable[Endorser-peer1.peers.org3.com] - start 
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: isConnectable[Endorser-peer1.peers.org3.com] - this servive endpoint has been connected
debug: [Channel]: addEndorser[supplychain] - adding a new Endorser  --name: peer1.peers.org3.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildChannel - added endorsing peer :: peer1.peers.org3.com
debug: [Client]: getEndorser: gateway client start name:peer1.peers.org2.com
debug: [Client]: getEndorser: gateway client existing endorser name:peer1.peers.org2.com
debug: [Client]: getEndorser: gateway client return endorser name:peer1.peers.org2.com
debug: [Channel]: addEndorser[supplychain] - start
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: isConnectable[Endorser-peer1.peers.org2.com] - start 
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: isConnectable[Endorser-peer1.peers.org2.com] - this servive endpoint has been connected
debug: [Channel]: addEndorser[supplychain] - adding a new Endorser  --name: peer1.peers.org2.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildChannel - added endorsing peer :: peer1.peers.org2.com
debug: [Client]: getCommitter: gateway client start name:ord1.orderers.org1.com
debug: [Client]: getCommitter: gateway client existing committer name:ord1.orderers.org1.com
debug: [Client]: getCommitter: gateway client return committer name:ord1.orderers.org1.com
debug: [Channel]: addCommitter[supplychain] - start
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: isConnectable[Committer-ord1.orderers.org1.com] - start 
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: isConnectable[Committer-ord1.orderers.org1.com] - this servive endpoint has been connected
debug: [Channel]: addCommitter[supplychain] - adding a new Committer  --name: ord1.orderers.org1.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildChannel - added orderer :: ord1.orderers.org1.com
debug: [Client]: getCommitter: gateway client start name:ord2.orderers.org1.com
debug: [Client]: getCommitter: gateway client existing committer name:ord2.orderers.org1.com
debug: [Client]: getCommitter: gateway client return committer name:ord2.orderers.org1.com
debug: [Channel]: addCommitter[supplychain] - start
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: isConnectable[Committer-ord2.orderers.org1.com] - start 
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: isConnectable[Committer-ord2.orderers.org1.com] - this servive endpoint has been connected
debug: [Channel]: addCommitter[supplychain] - adding a new Committer  --name: ord2.orderers.org1.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildChannel - added orderer :: ord2.orderers.org1.com
debug: [Client]: getCommitter: gateway client start name:ord3.orderers.org1.com
debug: [Client]: getCommitter: gateway client existing committer name:ord3.orderers.org1.com
debug: [Client]: getCommitter: gateway client return committer name:ord3.orderers.org1.com
debug: [Channel]: addCommitter[supplychain] - start
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: isConnectable[Committer-ord3.orderers.org1.com] - start 
debug: [ServiceEndpoint]: isConnectable[Committer-ord3.orderers.org1.com] - this servive endpoint has been connected
debug: [Channel]: addCommitter[supplychain] - adding a new Committer  --name: ord3.orderers.org1.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: buildChannel - added orderer :: ord3.orderers.org1.com
debug: [NetworkConfig]: loadFromConfig - end
debug: [Gateway]: connect - end
debug: [Gateway]: getNetwork - start
debug: [Gateway]: getNetwork - create network object and initialize
debug: [Client]: getChannel: gateway client start name:mychannel
debug: [Client]: getChannel: gateway client create channel name:mychannel
debug: [Channel]: Channel.constructor[mychannel] - start
debug: [Channel]: Channel.constructor[mychannel] - channel name is good mychannel
debug: [Channel]: Constructed Channel instance: name - mychannel
debug: [Client]: getChannel: gateway client return channel name:mychannel
debug: [Network]: constructor - start
debug: [EventSourceManager]: constructor - network:mychannel
debug: [BlockEventSource]: constructor - blockType:filtered
debug: [BlockEventSource]: constructor - blockType:full
debug: [BlockEventSource]: constructor - blockType:private
debug: [Network]: _initialize - start
debug: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel - start
debug: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel - end
debug: [Channel]: getEndorsers[mychannel] - start
debug: [Channel]: _getServiceEndpoints - start - ORG2MSP
debug: [Channel]: getEndorsers[mychannel] - start
debug: [Channel]: _getServiceEndpoints - start - undefined
debug: ******[SingleQueryHandler]: constructor: peers=[]******
debug: [Network]: _initialize - end
debug: [Channel]: getEndorsers[mychannel] - start
debug: [Channel]: _getServiceEndpoints - start - ORG2MSP
debug: [Channel]: getEndorsers[mychannel] - start
debug: [Channel]: _getServiceEndpoints - start - ORG3MSP
debug: [Channel]: getEndorsers[mychannel] - start
debug: [Channel]: _getServiceEndpoints - start - ORG1MSP
debug: [Channel]: getEndorser[mychannel] - start
debug: [Channel]: getEndorser[mychannel] - start
debug: [Channel]: getEndorser[mychannel] - start
debug: [Network]: getContract - start - name 
debug: [Contract]: constructor[] - start
debug: [Network]: getContract - create new contract mycontract
debug: [Transaction]: constructor[queryAllAssets] - start
debug: [IdentityContext]: calculateTransactionId - start
debug: [IdentityContext]: calculateTransactionId - nonce:b382d42b3bf653c6026546fc1a4f31549a2b3e771b641fa5
debug: [IdentityContext]: serializeIdentity - start
debug: [IdentityContext]: calculateTransactionId - txid:b27fb607cf7f956935227beb94db5ec9448d3a4557369ce19e079ccbf0059f8e
debug: [Transaction]: evaluate[queryAllAssets] - start
debug: [Channel]: newQuery[mychannel] - start
debug: [ServiceAction]: ServiceAction.constructor - start [mycontract]
debug: [Proposal]: Proposal.constructor[mycontract] - start 
debug: [Query]: constructor[mycontract] - start
debug: [Transaction]: evaluate[queryAllAssets] - build and sign the query
debug: [Proposal]: build[mycontract][Query] - start
debug: [Proposal]: build[mycontract][Query] - adding function queryAllAssets
debug: [Channel]: buildChannelHeader[mychannel] - start - type 3 chaincode_id mycontract tx_id b27fb607cf7f956935227beb94db5ec9448d3a4557369ce19e079ccbf0059f8e
debug: [Channel]: buildChannelHeader[mychannel] - chaincodeID {"name":"mycontract"}
debug: [Channel]: buildChannelHeader[mychannel] - ChaincodeHeaderExtension {"type":"Buffer","data":[18,9,18,7,104,117,98,108,105,116,101]}
debug: [Channel]: buildCurrentTimestamp[undefined] - start
debug: [Channel]: buildCurrentTimestamp[undefined] - seconds 1613997888 nanos 470000000
debug: [Client]: getClientCertHash: gateway client - start
debug: [Client]: getClientCertHash: gateway client - using clientCert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIErjCCA5a....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
debug: [ServiceAction]: buildHeader - start
debug: [IdentityContext]: serializeIdentity - start
debug: [ServiceAction]: sign[Query:mycontract] - start
debug: [IdentityContext]: sign - start
debug: [crypto_ecdsa_aes]: ecdsa signature:  negative=0, words=[5331593, 62136876, 2243398, 23004165, 59182575, 50607728, 58504872, 60139213, 49277563, 3236500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], length=10, red=null, negative=0, words=[46331108, 33127718, 30253667, 11340512, 57756519, 58555071, 64586586, 41625052, 39229940, 636498, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], length=10, red=null, recoveryParam=1
debug: [IdentityContext]: sign - end
debug: [ServiceAction]: sign[Query:mycontract] - end
debug: [Transaction]: evaluate[queryAllAssets] - handler will send
debug: [SingleQueryHandler]: evaluate - start
error: [SingleQueryHandler]: evaluate: message=Query failed. Errors: [], stack=FabricError: Query failed. Errors: []
    at SingleQueryHandler.evaluate (/fabric23/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/impl/query/singlequeryhandler.js:47:23)
    at Transaction.evaluate (/fabric23/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:276:49)
    at ContractImpl.evaluateTransaction (/fabric23/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/contract.js:179:45)
    at main (/fabric23/test.js:69:40)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5), name=FabricError
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening because the SingleQueryHandler was initialized without endorsing peers, as you can see in the log line

> ******[SingleQueryHandler]: constructor: peers=[]******

And the error log also doesn't help:

> error: [SingleQueryHandler]: evaluate: message=Query failed. Errors: [], stack=FabricError: Query failed. Errors: []

But it's not your fault since that's how the library handles errors on evaluation. I made this fluxogram in order to facilitate understanding over why empty endorsing peers list is a problem.

[image]

Understanding that, i think that the error may be solved by following what this user did in this another post: [Solved issue for finding peers in another organization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56209907/how-to-query-a-chaincode-from-outside-an-organization)

I've already sent a PR to their repositories to enhance their excpetion log error: [PR for log error enhancement](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/pull/489) . Of course, it doesn't solve the errors, but it gives a better feedback to developers. I'm facing this issue too recently.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue was that the peer's configs were incorrectly put in the connection config. Can you look into this issue that I am facing now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66390671/hyperledger-fabric-2-3-connection-issue